# How to obtain the pole zero map and step response of the 2nd order system and determine the mode of damping in the system using MATLAB?

Tags: control, control-system, matlab, pole-zeroplot

> $$\frac{C(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta \omega_n s+\omega_n^2}$$
>
> Obtain the pole zero map and step response of the 2nd order system and determine the mode of damping in the system. If the system is underdamped obtain the time domain specifications. On the pole zero map show that corresponding damping ratio and natural undamped frequency of the poles.

\$\omega_n = 3 r/s\$ and \$\zeta =1\$

The problem is that I am still confused about how to calculate it using MATLAB. All I know is how to calculate it manually. Maybe someone knows how to calculate it in MATLAB.

Comment: Lack of information and intention.

Comment: You're just asking "how do I solve an equation in Matlab"; matlab itself doesn't solve equations, it applies mathematical operations that might be solving equations (for example, it could invert a matrix to find a solution to a system of linear equations). It has the symbolic toolbox (an add-on you can buy) that can parse and within limits solve symbolic equations. But essentially, wrong tool for automatic solution; it's your problem to find a method to solve the equation. Matlab can do the calculations.

Comment: What does "the mode of damping" mean? Your first formula and paragraph below it are formatted as a quote. You should cite that quote with a reference.

Comment: @Andyaka Damping modes include over-damped, critical, and under-damped systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I created and it solves that problem.

```
    clc
    clear

    % Declaration of Omega_n Value
    wn = 3;

    % Zeta Values for Each Variation
    z1 = 1;
    z2 = 2;
    z3 = 0.1;
    z4 = 0.5;
    z5 = 0;

    % Numerator and Denominator Values for Each Variation
    num1 = wn^2;
    den1 = [1 2*z1*wn wn^2];

    num2 = wn^2;
    den2 = [1 2*z2*wn wn^2];

    num3 = wn^2;
    den3 = [1 2*z3*wn wn^2];

    num4 = wn^2;
    den4 = [1 2*z4*wn wn^2];

    num5 = wn^2;
    den5 = [1 2*z5*wn wn^2];

    figure;

    % When Zeta = 1
    sys_tf1 = tf(num1, den1);

    % Pole Zero Map
    subplot(2,5,1)
    pzmap(sys_tf1);
    title(['Pole Zero Map (Zeta = ', num2str(z1), ')'])

    % Step Response
    subplot(2,5,6)
    step(sys_tf1);
    title(['Step Response (Zeta = ', num2str(z1), ')'])

    % When Zeta = 2
    sys_tf2 = tf(num2, den2);

    % Pole Zero Map
    subplot(2,5,2)
    pzmap(sys_tf2);
    title(['Pole Zero Map (Zeta = ', num2str(z2), ')'])

    % Step Response
    subplot(2,5,7)
    step(sys_tf2);
    title(['Step Response (Zeta = ', num2str(z2), ')'])

    % When Zeta = 0.1
    sys_tf3 = tf(num3, den3);

    % Pole Zero Map
    subplot(2,5,3)
    pzmap(sys_tf3);
    title(['Pole Zero Map (Zeta = ', num2str(z3), ')'])

    % Step Response
    subplot(2,5,8)
    step(sys_tf3);
    title(['Step Response (Zeta = ', num2str(z3), ')'])

    % When Zeta = 0.5
    sys_tf4 = tf(num4, den4);

    % Pole Zero Map
    subplot(2,5,4)
    pzmap(sys_tf4);
    title(['Pole Zero Map (Zeta = ', num2str(z4), ')'])

    % Step Response
    subplot(2,5,9)
    step(sys_tf4);
    title(['Step Response (Zeta = ', num2str(z4), ')'])

    % When Zeta = 0
    sys_tf5 = tf(num5, den5);

    % Pole Zero Map
    subplot(2,5,5)
    pzmap(sys_tf5);
    title(['Pole Zero Map (Zeta = ', num2str(z5), ')'])

    % Step Response
    subplot(2,5,10)
    step(sys_tf5,5);
    title(['Step Response (Zeta = ', num2str(z5), ')'])

    % Displaying damping mode information and time domain specifications
    for z = [z1, z2, z3, z4, z5]
        if z == 0
            disp(['Mode of damping for Zeta = ', num2str(z), ': Undamped']);
        elseif 0 < z && z < 1
            % Displaying damping mode information
            disp(['Mode of damping for Zeta = ', num2str(z), ': Underdamped']);
            
            % Calculating and displaying time domain specifications
            % Rise Time
            tr = pi / (wn * sqrt(1 - z^2));
            disp(['Rise Time: ', num2str(tr)]);
            
            % Settling Time
            ts = 4 / (z * wn);
            disp(['Settling Time: ', num2str(ts)]);
            
            % Natural Frequency of Oscillation
            fn = wn * sqrt(1 - z^2);
            disp(['Natural Frequency of Oscillation: ', num2str(fn)]);
        elseif z == 1
            disp(['Mode of damping for Zeta = ', num2str(z), ': Critically Damped']);
        elseif z > 1
            disp(['Mode of damping for Zeta = ', num2str(z), ': Overdamped']);
        end
        disp(' '); % Empty line break
    end
```